# Is it possible to connect to Modbus TCP via Ethernet?

Tags: modbus, raspberry-pi4

Is it possible to connect the Ethernet port (of a Raspberry Pi) directly to a Modbus TCP RJ45 port (such that the devices can talk to each other)? Or is this not possible without a converter?

I am unsure if this is the correct forum, but I believe this should not be specific to the Raspberry pi.

Comment: Its possible but you need TCP connectivity before ModbusTCP has any chance of working. The [Pi](https://elinux.org/RPi_Hardware#Components) supports [Auto MDI-X](https://superuser.com/q/186460) so a cross-over cable is not needed. You will, however, have to manually configure IP addresses etc on both sides. [Superuser](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) is probably a better site for your question (because it's not really related to [Software Development](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)).

Comment: thanks for your comment. Then how do I request a admin to migrate my question to that site?

Comment: Not sure if you can (I have just voted to close with the reason that it's more suited to SuperUser). However I think the comment above should answer your question as asked (yes - it is possible) so not sure if there is any benefit moving this (if the comment does not answer your question then you will need to provide further details).

Comment: yeah, after your comment, I found a video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=290&v=EAXJ_3dfeNI&feature=emb_logo, which shows exactly what you described. So if you want, post an answer and I will accept

Comment: But coming to think about it, can I then use this also plug this into a hub or switch?

Comment: Absolutely; however, unless there is a DHCP service on the network, you will need to manually configure the IP settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer - Yes... But....

As per the comments this is possible but there are a few things you will need to do (i.e. some configuration will be needed).

I think it's worth nothing that "Modbus TCP RJ45 port" is not really a meaningful term. Modbus is an [application layer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_layer) protocol; this depends upon a number of underlying layers:

- [Transport layer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_layer) - [TCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol)
- [Network layer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_layer) - [IP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Protocol)
- [Datalink Layer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_link_layer) - [Ethernet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet)
- [Physical Layer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_layer) - [Ethernet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_physical_layer) cable with RJ45 connectors

You don't need to understand this in detail; the point is that before ModbusTCP will work you need to have a working TCP network (which all Modbus-TCP devices will support; generally via an RJ45 Ethernet connection). As such a better question probably is "If I run a [CAT-5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_5_cable) cable between a Raspberry Pi and another device (Modbus TCP unit) will I be able to connect via TCP?" (a lot more people know about TCP/IP networking than Modbus!).

The first thing to consider is Ethernet. Running a cable directly between two older devices will often not work because they needed a [crossover cable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crossover_cable). Almost all modern equipment (including the [Pi](https://elinux.org/RPi_Hardware#Components)) supports [Auto MDI-X](https://superuser.com/q/186460) which means the cable will just work. You can also connect the units via a switch (and doing this removes the need for Auto MDI-X).

Next you need to consider the IP layer. When you connect your Pi to your home network it will (usually!) be given an IP address by a DHCP service (usually running on your router). If you are connecting the Pi directly to the device then there will be no DHCP service so you will need to manually assign IP addresses to the devices (and ensure the subnet is correctly configured). A common way to check if an IP connection is working is to use the [`ping`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ping_(networking_utility)) command.

With the lower layers working ModbusTCP will generally 'just work'. Many ModbusTCP devices also offer a browser based configuration and checking that you can access that is a good way to confirm that the network link is working.

One further question is probably "should I do this"; it's OK to hook things up this way to make some quick changes. However generally you will want the Pi to access other network resources so connecting everything to a router (home router will work; for remote devices a cell router is often used). You can either give the Modbus unit a static IP manually or use the routers configuration pages to assign it a static DHCP lease (otherwise it's IP might change from time to time).

Comment: So this worked exactly as intended. I can now talk to the intended  device directly. I also realize that this question arises from a misunderstanding, which your answer explains very nicely :D. If you have a tip on how I can improve my question such that it serves better for future reference, please go ahead!